# 'is cause' vs. 'it causes'

Tags: grammar

In the grammar test below, Why option 3 is not correct?

> Only where market failure occurs ------ to worry, and even such
>   failure may tend to excessive conservation.
>
> 1)is there perhaps cause (correct answer)
>
> 2)does it perhaps cause
>
> 3)it perhaps causes us
>
> 4)perhaps there is cause us

*I just could find the context source [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=S3zZ18tt3gkC&pg=PA130&lpg=PA130&dq=only%20where%20market%20failure%20occurs%20is%20there%20perhaps&source=bl&ots=C-yOvLH04M&sig=ACfU3U23PPgPWzIGl-acCOduhw4Jaj998g&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiC5pHc-dXpAhX_TxUIHbeyDd0Q6AEwAHoECAcQAQ#v=onepage&q=only%20where%20market%20failure%20occurs%20is%20there%20perhaps&f=false).*

**Any help is really appreciated!**

Comment: You'll want to have a look at 'inversion after negative or limiting adverbials' which should help you understand why number 3 is not the right answer.

Comment: @JMB ,That was a HELP. Could you do me a favor, please? Show me what would be the structure of the correctly filled sentence before inversion; so I can understand the exact process of inversion in it. The correct answer would be like this: "Only where market failure occurs is there perhaps cause to worry, and even such failure may tend to excessive conservation." Many Thanks, my friend!

Comment: It's a little tricky since the sentence works so well in its current form. To avoid inversion 'only' must not be at the beginning, so maybe "There is perhaps cause to worry only in situations where market failure occurs..."